# Почему PyQt интерфейс выглядит по-другому после компиляции pyinstaller'ом?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller

Есть программа. Вот так она выглядит при запуске интерпретатором

[image]

Вскоре мне понадобилось её скомпилировать. Для себя я выбрал Pyinstaller. После компиляции программа выглядит так. P.S. Всё выполнялось в одной системе.

[image]

И что с этим делать? Что вообще случилось с интерфейсом?

Comment: Можете поделиться минимальным кодом для анализа?

Comment: @S.Nick каким именно?

Comment: Вы пишите: `Есть программа. Вот так она выглядит при запуске интерпретатором`. Речь идет об этой программе.

Comment: @S.Nick я не думаю, что он тут понадобится. Тут косяки в дизайне, я все делал в Qt Designer.

Comment: Так выложите файл.ui

Comment: @S.Nick мне кто-то сказал, что не хватает xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Текущая версия PyInstaller 3.3.1 не полностью совместима с последней версией PyQt5 (после 5.9.2). Работа над [исправлением](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/pull/3233) идёт.

Comment: Поставил старую версию, все работает