# Куда пропала красота? pyqt5 pyInstaller

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller

После сборки пропали красивые обводки вокруг кнопок.. Слева с запуска .py, а с права .exe[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43956908/pyqt5-python-qapplication-setstyle-not-working тут

Comment: Интересно, а что http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstylefactory.html#keys возвращает? Какие элементы в списке? А какой объект стиля возвращает приложение http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#style? Просто, стили можно принудительно указывать (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2448123/5909792), иначе Qt будет брать дефолтное, и мб у вас как раз такая ситуация

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему PyQt интерфейс выглядит по-другому после компиляции pyinstaller'ом?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/848523/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-pyqt-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b3%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-pyinstaller%d0%be%d0%bc)

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev c одной стороны да, а с другой нет